# STB loads image, but shows black texture

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to transfer my Slick Utils texture code to STB texture code, but when I run the program, all I see is a black rotating cube, when it should have a texture on each face of the cube. I've have tried hard-coding the texture loading in the material class and that is not working. It may be in the Renderer class, because I load up the texture in OpenGL, but it may be incorrect.

**Material (which is texture) Class**

```
package engine.rendering;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import engine.io.Image;

public class Material {
    private int textureID;

    public Material(String file) {
        textureID = GL11.glGenTextures();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        Image image = Image.loadImage("res/textures/" + file);
        GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getImage());
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    public void remove() {
        GL11.glDeleteTextures(textureID);
    }

    public int getTextureID() {
        return textureID;
    }
}
```

**Image Loader Class**

```
package engine.io;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage;
import org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack;

public class Image {
    public ByteBuffer getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return heigh;
    }

    private ByteBuffer image;
    private int width, heigh;

    Image(int width, int heigh, ByteBuffer image) {
        this.image = image;
        this.heigh = heigh;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public static Image loadImage(String path) {
        ByteBuffer image;
        int width, heigh;
        try (MemoryStack stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {
            IntBuffer comp = stack.mallocInt(1);
            IntBuffer w = stack.mallocInt(1);
            IntBuffer h = stack.mallocInt(1);

            image = STBImage.stbi_load(path, w, h, comp, 4);
            if (image == null) {
                System.err.println("Couldn't load " + path);
            }
            width = w.get();
            heigh = h.get();
        }
        return new Image(width, heigh, image);
    }
}
```

**Renderer Class**

```
package engine.rendering;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

import engine.io.Window;
import engine.maths.Matrix4f;
import engine.rendering.models.ModelEntity;
import engine.rendering.models.TexturedModel;
import engine.rendering.models.UntexturedModel;
import engine.shaders.BasicShader;

public class Renderer {
    private BasicShader shader;
    private Window window;

    public Renderer(Window window, BasicShader shader) {
        this.shader = shader;
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void create() {
        shader.loadProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4f().projection(70.0f, (float) window.getWidth() / window.getHeight(), 0.1f, 1000.0f));
    }

    public void renderModel(UntexturedModel model){
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVertexArrayID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void renderTexturedModel(TexturedModel model){
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVertexArrayID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, model.getMaterial().getTextureID());
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void renderModelEntity(ModelEntity entity){
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(entity.getModel().getVertexArrayID());
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(entity.getTransformationMatrix());
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, entity.getModel().getMaterial().getTextureID());
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, entity.getModel().getVertexCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The texture sampler returns black because the default filter mode requires mipmaps. You can either generate mipmaps (`glGenerateMipmaps()`) or you can change the filter mode to a mode that doesn't require mipmaps:

```
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
```